# Pandas: concat multiple new columns to an existing data-frame based on the value of one of the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using Pandas, I have a data-frame in hand:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 9 |
| 1 | b | 9 |
| 2 | c | 9 |

Iterating through all rows (one by one), based on the A column, I load (from a ZipFile) an additional columns in the form of a dictionary (some of which are missing - need to eliminate the whole row). Result should look simillar to that:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 9 | a-foo | a-bar |
| 2 | c | 9 | c-foo | c-bar |

What is the best method to use for the iteration? Tried several options, among which are for-in, apply,map, but it usually fails on typing issues (I'm quite new to that).

Any help or directions will be truely appreciated.

Comment: Your question is unclear, there are many details missing

Comment: I'll try to further explain. I have this DataFrame with several existing rows and columns. I need to iterate all rows. In each row I take the value of col A and load an additional data based on that value (think of an Id value, e.g. 'my-unique-id'). When loaded, I need to concat the additional data to the original DataFrame on that same index. If no additional data exist, I need to ignore/remove that index from DataFrame.
That's about it.

Comment: Right. So, please share a data sample of the "additional data". What does it look like. E.g. a dict? `{'a': ['foo', 'bar'], 'c': ['foo', 'bar']}`, where the first val in the list needs to come in col `C`, the second in col `D`? Anyway, we cannot help you, if we don't know what sort of data needs to be added, and in what form it arrives.

Comment: For the first row you should expect the dictionary to be `{'A': 'a', 'C': 'a-foo', 'D': 'a-bar'}`, where the common key is column A. The second row with 'b' value of col A is missing its additional data, and thus should be removed. The third row loads `{'A': 'c', 'C': 'c-foo', 'D': 'c-bar'}`. That's the main concept, but in reality it involves few dozen columns, so I'm looking for a less imperative codng.

Comment: Probably best to create a second df with your new data then use `merge`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume your data looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}, 
        'B': {0: 9, 1: 9, 2: 9}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

data2 = [{'A': 'a', 'C': 'a-foo', 'D': 'a-bar'},
         {'A': 'c', 'C': 'c-foo', 'D': 'c-bar'}]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

You can combine [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`df.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) to merge the two `dfs` and drop the rows (here: only the row with index 1) that end up with `NaN` values in the process:

```
df.merge(df2, on='A', how='left').dropna(axis=0, subset=['C','D'], how='all')

   A  B      C      D
0  a  9  a-foo  a-bar
2  c  9  c-foo  c-bar
```

Comment: That would be risky, as I might drop rows including nan on the left df. I only want to drop rows which does not have it's additional columns from the right.

Comment: Right. Updated the answer. It will only check of `NaN` values in the columns that were added after the merge.

Comment: @ChenEshchar: any luck with implementing the updated answer? If so, maybe consider accepting the answer to close the question.